# Aligning Span Fields to the Left while Aligning Form Center

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where I am using `text-align` on my container to center all of the content within it, but would like to align my `<span>` elements to the left within that centered container. I have tried isolating the span elements in my css and using `text-align: left;` but have not had any success. I feel like it is a simple fix that is slipping my mind at the moment, but hope that it can be easily resolved.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-1" id="bar-registration-container">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <div id="form-fields">
            <form>
                <label class="form-label" id="email">
                    <span>Email</span>
                    <br />
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label class="form-label" id="password">
                    <span>Password</span>
                    <br />
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                    <input class="form-label" id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bar-registration-container h1{
    text-align: center;
}

#form-fields {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}


#form-fields input[type=email] {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#form-fields input[type=password] {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-label span {
    color: #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#submit {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this snippet accomplishes what you want. I just gave the `form-fields` div a set width, and added a few styles to those `span` elements to get them to stretch the full width of that div, but be left-aligned.

```css
#bar-registration-container h1{
    text-align: center;
}

#form-fields {
    width: 340px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}


#form-fields input[type=email] {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#form-fields input[type=password] {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-label span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#submit {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-1" id="bar-registration-container">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <div id="form-fields">
            <form>
                <label class="form-label" id="email">
                    <span>Email</span>
                    <br />
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label class="form-label" id="password">
                    <span>Password</span>
                    <br />
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                    <input class="form-label" id="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to left align your `<span>` you need to left align them and in edition to that you will have to use `display:block`. You actually were on right track you just missed `display:block`. Using `display:block` will make your `<span>` to act as a block element like `<div>` or `<p>` and then it will respect alignment properties better.

```
span{
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    margin-left:50px;// adjust yourself. Was just playing around with it.
}
```